# Extensions of minimal hypersurfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

Let $B \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ be the unit ball, and $M \subset B$ be a minimal hypersurface. By this we mean that $M$ is an embedded $n$-dimensional submanifold with vanishing mean curvature. We allow for the closure $\overline{M}$ of $M$ in $B$ to not be embedded, write $\mathrm{sing} \, M = \overline{M} \setminus M$ and call this the *singular set* of $M$. However this is assumed to be small enough for $M$ to be *stationary* in $B$: compactly supported deformations $X \in C_c^1(B;\mathbf{R}^{n+1})$ do not change the area of $M$ up to first order. For example one might take $n \geq 2$ and consider a surface $M$ embedded outside the origin with $\mathrm{sing} \, M = \{ 0 \}$.

**Question 1**. Are there conditions that allow the extension of $M$ to a globally defined immersed minimal hypersurface in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$? That is, when is there a minimal hypersurface $\tilde{M}$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ (immersed away from a small singular set) with $\tilde{M} \cap B = M$?

Let me make some remarks summarising my own conclusions.

- The [Cauchy--Kovalevskaya theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem) could be relevant, but I am not sure whether this can be used to construct a globally defined extension. Moreover, one would have to worry about pieces coming together and meeting tangentially.
- This is not a purely PDE-theoretic question. If one considers the case where $M$ is the graph of a smooth function $u$ defined on $\mathbf{R}^n \cap B$---this function satisfies the (quasi-linear) minimal surface equation---then it is not hard to see that $u$ can in general not be extended to a globally defined function $\tilde{u}: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$. The [Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_problem) is one way to see this, but also simple examples can be constructed using a suitable portion of the [catenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid).
- One can use the unique continuation property of minimal surfaces against the question, by taking $M$ to be a portion of a known surface. For example, by taking $M$ to be an embedded portion of an immersed minimal surface $\tilde{M}$ one can see that one cannot hope for a globally defined and *embedded* minimal extension. Moreover, if one chooses $M$ to be portion of a singly-periodic [Scherk surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scherk_surface) one sees that $\tilde{M}$ may have unbounded area growth: $\lim_{R \to \infty} \mathcal{H}^n(\tilde{M} \cap B_R)/R^n = \infty$.

I am especially interested in the case where $M$ is one of the surfaces constructed by [Caffarelli--Hardt--Simon](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01168999). These are defined in $B$, embedded outside the origin, where they are prescribed to be tangent to a given minimal cone $\mathbf{C}$.

**Question 2**. How does the answer change if $M$ is one of those surfaces? Is there $\tilde{M}$ extending $M$, perhaps even with bounded area growth, that is with a constant $C > 0$ so that $\mathcal{H}^n(\tilde{M} \cap B_R) \leq C R^n$ for all radii $R > 1$?

Comment: What does "globally defined" mean?  A proper immersion?  If so then one can use Nadirashvilli's examples to see that one can't even ensure this.  In any event I doubt there is any checkable condition.  One sometimes sees real analyticity up to the boundary to extend a little bit, but that is far from what you are asking.

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you for the comment; I had forgotten about Nadirashvili's surfaces. I was a bit vague in my statement, and avoided the term 'proper immersion' because I was worried that the small singular set might make this fail on a technicality. I wanted to avoid using too many terms from GMT, but to be precise 'globally defined' would mean something like the following: the surface $\tilde{M}$ has locally finite area densities, and defines a stationary varifold in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$. I guess the local finiteness would work like a GMT-analog of properness.

Comment: @RBega2 In any case you're right the Nadirashvili example is troublesome, I'm happy to concede. By rescaling and Allard regularity you can have $M$ arbitrarily close to the plane which does not admit 'global' extensions. However I'll leave the question up, in the hope that somebody might comment on Question 2 in particular.